# jquery dialog - cannot disable button on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to disable some buttons (with some additional conditions) on jquery dialog show and I am unable to do this. I tried many different ways and none of them worked. I am out of ideas.

Example code attached (in coffeescript):

```
$('#messages').dialog({
  height: 500,
  width: 800,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  show: 'fade', 
  hide: 'clip',
  buttons: [
      {
      id: "msg-close",
      text: "Close",
      click: ->
        $('#msg-close').prop('disabled', true) //this one works
      }
    ],
  open: ->
    $('#msg-close').prop('disabled', true) //this one doesnt work
});

$('#msg-close').prop('disabled', true) //this one doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0):

[open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) expects a function like this

```
open: function () {
    $('#msg-close').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: it is coffeescript and it is a function. If i will put there anything - lets say some simple console.log it will work. Just disabling button doesn't